# Unable to login using Spotify iOS SDK Simple Track example if swap service defined

Tags: ios, spotify

Using **Spotify iOS SDK Beta-16**.

The Simple Track sample application included with the SDK works fine out of the box; can login, play, etc.

However, if the `#defines` for `kTokenSwapServiceURL` and `kTokenRefreshServiceURL` are uncommented, and the urls changed to point to services running on the mac, login attempts fail. Message in console reads

```
Simple Track Playback[7320:1359057] *** Failed to log in: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) 
UserInfo=0x165f6260 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Basically, some attempt to parse json is failing.

The services are never hit. It appears that just the act of defining the endpoints causes a different code path to be executed in the framework, which is failing. Comment out those `#defines` and everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when you define **kTokenSwapServiceUR**L and **kTokenRefreshServiceURL**, your app will try to swap and refresh the token automatically so your service is not work as expected. If you commented these it will just open safari and login again and again everytime but if you don't it will try just refresh and swap token not login.

I solved my issue by using heroku. This is the [github project](https://github.com/simontaen/SpotifyTokenSwap) to do this and I had used it. If you follow the instructions you will be able to refresh and swap the token automatically.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well, the services referenced by kTokenSwapServiceURL (e.g., http://192.168.1.9:8888/swap_token) and kTokenRefreshServiceURL do exist and are working. node.js implementation. Even tested that they were accessible from the app using NSMutableURLRequest. It's just that the spotify sdk never even hits them after the login prompt is dismissed, and the login attempt ultimately fails with the error previously mentioned. - Thanks!

Comment: Did you check issues on github like these: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/159 and https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/178#issuecomment-65935222